# mysql-connector-python adds single quotes around table name when table is passed as argument. Table name comes from Flask session variable

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-connector-python

I am new to MySQL and I am building a Flask project and using `mysql.connector` to query a MySQL Database. I know this question has been answered many times before but this is more specific to using MySQL with Flask.

I need to pass a query where I want to plug in the table name into the query, dynamically, depending on the value stored in the `session` variable in Flask. But the problem is, if I try to do:

**Method 1:**

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM %s;',(session['table_name'],))
```

the database throws an error stating that such a table is not found. However, the problem is `mysql.connector` keeps enclosing the table name with single quotes, hence the error.

Sample Error Statement:

`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''52_data'' at line 1`

Here the table name should be `52_data` and not `'52_data'`.

Only other workaround, I figured, is using:

**Method 2:**

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM '+session['table_name']+';')
```

which is working but it does not escape SQL Injection, I am guessing, since it's direct concatenation, unlike Method 1, where the `cur.execute()` function handles the escaping, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540803/escaping-strings-with-python-mysql-connector).

The value being passed is stored in a sessions variable in Flask, which is not so secure, as per [Miguel's Video](https://youtu.be/mhcnBTDLxCI). Hence, I want to escape that string, without triggering off an error.

Is it possible to implement Method 1 in a way that it does not add the quotes, or maybe escape the string using some function? Or maybe any other Python/Flask package that can handle this problem better?

Or if nothing works, is checking for SQL Injection manually using regex is a wiser option?

Thanks in advance.

Note: The package name for this `mysql.connector` is `mysql-connector-python` and not any other same sounding package.

Answer (score 0):

For identifiers, you can use something like:

```
table_name = conn.converter.escape(session['table_name'])
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM `{}`'.format(table_name))
```

For values placeholders, you can use your **Method 1**, by using the parameters in the `cur.execute()` method. They will be escaped and quoted.

More details in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

**NOTE**: You don't need to end the SQL statements with `;`