# Getting Error while Inserting a row to MYSQL using Python

Tags: mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to add a row in mysql table using python.

```
cursor.execute(
        "insert into tbl_ft1x2s (match_id, fair_odds, mkt_odds, pred_prob, return, edge, scatter_edge, scatter_trend, hist_prob, smpl_prop) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (match_id, fair_odds_1, mkt_odds_1, pred_prob_1, exp_return_1, edge_1, scatter_edge, scatter_trend, hist_prob_1,
         smpl_prop_1))
```

I'm getting this error,

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'return, edge, scatter_edge, scatter_trend, hist_prob, smpl_prop) values (87507, ' at line 1
```

match_id is int while rest of all the columns are varchar.

I think issue is that the name of column "return" is a keyword in MYSQL. Am I right ? If yes then can anyone help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly you want me to add double % ?

Comment: that's not working

Comment: I had your exact problem a year ago (I think...), and I know that I needed %%. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings for other ideas then. Btw., if you can avoid insert and are fine with just creating a new table, I recommend to use df.to_sql(), see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html.

Comment: Perhaps you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540803/escaping-strings-with-python-mysql-connector.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the keyword `return` as a field name. That is probably why you have that error near that part of your SQL statement.

Here is a [list of the reserved keywords in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

To avoid the problem, just add the backtick (`) around keywords.